# How to Deserialize JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization, webclient

I'm working on project in which I'm Posting data from asp.net webform to WCF service. I'm posting data through params and the service respond me back a `JSON string`. Now I have an issue in deserialize. I read many threads but didn't find any solution. Hope someone can sort out my problem. Thanks in Advance

**Response from WCF**

{"LoginResult":false}

I just want `"false"` value.

**How I tried:**

```
    string URL = "http://localhost:32319/ServiceEmployeeLogin.svc"; 
    WebRequest wrGETURL;
    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(URL+"/"+emp_username+"/"+emp_password+"/"+emp_type);
    wrGETURL.Method = "POST";
    wrGETURL.ContentType = @"application/json; charset=utf-8";
    HttpWebResponse webresponse = wrGETURL.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    // read response stream from response object
    StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

    // read string from stream data
    strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

    var jObj = JObject.Parse(strResult);
    var dict = jObj["LoginResult"].Children().Cast<JProperty>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use json.net to do it like this:

```
public class AuthResponse {
    public bool LoginResult { get; set; }
}

var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponse>(strResult);
```

http://james.newtonking.com/json

Answer (score 2):

.Net 4.5 has a JavaScriptSerializer, which should work as well:

```
public class AuthResponse {
    public bool LoginResult { get; set; }
}

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer sr = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

AuthResponse response = sr.Deserialize<AuthResponse>(responseText);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx